# Unit testing javascript for a memory leak

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, memory-leaks

Is there a way to unit test for javascript memory leaks?  What I mean is, is there any way to access the heap directly from javascript code to check for detached DOM trees or increased memory usage?

I know you can do this from Chrome Dev Tools, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it directly from my unit tests, since it seems tedious to write some code, take a heap snapshot, perform a potentially memory leaking operation, take another heap snapshot, and repeat for every single potentially memory leaking operation, every time a write another snippet of code.  Not to mention that adding code in one place may cause an unexpected memory leak in another part of the application.

It's just that I wrote an application that had a huge memory leak, and I had to start from scratch.  When I develop the application this time around, I want to make sure my unit tests can detect that I've just created a memory leak, and I can eliminate it as soon as possible.

I think I've seen tools like this for C++, but not for Javascript.  Does anyone know of any?  Thank you!

Comment: Chrome developer tools -> Profiles.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To check memory leaks, You need to have access to memory allocation size or size of Your variables. There's no possibility to do it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

According to [MDN's docs on window.performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/performance), Google Chrome has a non-standard extension ([window.performance.memory](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/timing/properties/memory)) that gives access to values like usedJSHeapSize, totalJSHeapSize, jsHeapSizeLimit.

To get byte-level precision, you need to use the `--enable-precise-memory-info` flag.

For Garbage Collection, the only way I've found to force a browser to perform GC is with Chromium, with a special command flag. 
When you run this command:

```
chromium-browser --js-flags='--expose_gc'
```

you get access to the method `window.gc()`, which you can call to force GC.

This may open the possibility for testing memory usage in unit tests, for example.

Answer (score 1):

For Node.js there's [leakage](https://github.com/andywer/leakage) that can be used to perform memory related unit tests. If your test involves DOM, you may try using [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) to simulate the browser behavior, but I cannot guarantee it will give you the same result.